# How to send some extra fields while uploading images?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, codeigniter

I am creating a dynamic slider. Like in side admin can upload images for slider and that will be shown in front side. I am uploading multiple images. All this code is ready and working successfully but my client want that:

1. While adding images he need a URL for each image must be saved in db
   so that when any one user click on the image(in slider) she / he
   should go to that saved URL for that image.
2. There should be a separate  timing for each to here timing means how much time that image must be stay in slider as we know in slider all the images moving continuously.

As I am uploading multiple images how can I set separate URL and timing for each image

I need something like when I browse images (only browse not upload) there the images i browsed will me shown and under each image there will be two text boxes for key in URL and time. This is the solution but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading image from admin side, create 2 extra fields for image URL and Image Delay time.

And then save them into DB

And while rendering those images onto front-end ... use your loop to generate the links along with image. Something like that

```
foreach($images as $img){
?>
<a href="<?php echo $img['link'] ?>"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $img['img_url'] ?>" />    
 </a>
<?php
}
```

The other question of having different delay in each image. It depends upon which Image Slider are you using.

You first have to find and Image Slider Plugin which allows to have different delays in each slide